# (iBatis) I want to insert multiple data list in a table

Tags: spring, loops, sequence, ibatis, nextval

I develop web application using Spring and iBatis. I want to insert multiple data in a table. I throw *DataMap* including *ArrayList* in controller as follow.

```
param.put("aList", aList);
param.put("aaaSeq", aaaSeq);

commonDAO.insert(namespace, "insertAAA", param);
```

In ibatis,

```
<insert id="insertAAA" parameterClass="dmap">   
<selectKey keyProperty="aaaSeq" resultClass="java.lang.Integer" type="pre">
        SELECT a_seq.nextval FROM DUAL
</selectKey>    
insert into AAA
    (
      aSeq, 
      a, 
    )
<iterate property="aList" open="(" close=")" conjunction=" union all ">
select      
    #aaaSeq#,
    #aList[]#
from 
    dual
</iterate>      
</insert>
```

However, it have an error related with **Integrity Constraints**.

So, I wondering how to insert multiple data in a single table.

Comment: Did you managed to solve it? I'm facing the same issue.